# Jquery spritespin integration with angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins

I new to angular js. I want to implement with angular js.

Here is my code.

**index.html**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="headerController">
    <span ng-repeat="b in button" > 
         <button button-control id='{{b}}' ng-click = '{{b}}()'>{{b}}</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
.controller('headerController',function($scope,$location){
     $scope.button = ['prev','toggle','reserve','next'];
 })
.directive('buttonControl',function(){
    return{
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: true,
      link:function(scope,elem,attrs){
      var api = elem.spritespin('api');
      scope.prev = function(){               
       api.stopAnimation(); //**problem**
      }
      scope.toggle = function(){

      }
      scope.reserve = function(){

      }
      scope.next = function(){

      }
  }
}
```

})

**Problem**
when i do api.stopAnimation(), stopAnimation() uses this object which points to current scope instead of elem. I might  be wrong on this.

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through chrome AngularJS Batarang and i have to do

```
scope.$parent.$parent.api = new Object
```

to override parent scope

now in buttonController directives. I can access api object by just doing

```
 app.directive('buttonControl',function(){
    return{
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    link:function(scope,elem,attrs){
        console.log(scope.api);
    }
})
```